# Need help understanding Dennard's scaling and multicore processors

Tags: processor

I am currently studying computer architecture and came across the following statement: "Around 2006, Dennard’s scaling did not hold anymore. As a consequence, larger processor manufacturers started to produce multicore processors." I am having trouble understanding this statement and would appreciate any help or clarification.

As far as my understanding goes, Dennard's scaling refers to the trend where as transistor size decreased, the power density remained constant, allowing for an increase in the number of transistors on a chip while maintaining the same power consumption. However, I am not sure why this statement suggests that Dennard's scaling did not hold anymore in 2006 and how it relates to the development of multicore processors.

I would be grateful if anyone could explain this concept to me in simple terms or point me in the right direction to further understand it. Also, if there are any resources or references that could help me better comprehend this topic, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What research papers do the processor manufacturers show? or the research labs?

Comment: It is saying that since Dennard scaling (which enabled a large increase of clock frequency each generation) ended, improving performance required using more cores at lower frequency since there was no other way to improve performance.  Does that answer your question or is there more that you're not getting?

Comment: @user1850479 I see, so the statement is true then. Thanks!